# by appending div loosing its style

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, division

Division which I want to clone has a particular position. How can I append with other division I have.

My div styling code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4"></div>
<div class="col-xs-8  verticalLine" id="nestedFeilds"  style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left; display: none;">
```

here its link
https://screenshots.firefox.com/TAqBN5IIT8atR6lA/localhost

and where I render above code is

```
<div class= "row" id="2ndmainContainer">
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8  verticalLine" id="showhere"  style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left;">
    </div>
</div>
```

soon after my "nestedFeilds" div ends. I have "showhere" div it appears only on "col-xs-8" of row and "col-xs-4" is not working
after append function it comes like this

https://screenshots.firefox.com/IngUgWgQTJeAjlOC/localhost

jquery function for appending

```
$(document).ready(function() {


 $("#addNew").click(function() {
    var maindiv = document.getElementById('nestedFeilds').innerHTML;
    $("#showhere").append(maindiv);
     maindiv.attr('name', 'myid');
  });
});
```

here it is jsfiddle but here it is not working
https://jsfiddle.net/r9wtcsj9/

Comment: can you make a fiddle or give your output as image, so we can understand better and help you

Comment: i have give screen shots please take a reveiw

Comment: can you post full code?

Comment: I think it will be better if you provide the entire HTML and JS which you have already tried or provide a JS Fiddle with the problem at hand.

Comment: sir i have provide jsfiddle but there its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you (view in full screen to see the results). You can see the changes I have made to include `col-md-1` and `col-md-5` for both the columns and removed inline styles for `label`. Rest of your code remains the same.

```js
$("#addNew, #addNew1").click(function () {
 if ($("#nestedFeilds").is(":visible")) {
  $("#showhere").append($("#nestedFeilds").html());
  $("#2ndmainContainer").show();
 }

 $("#nestedFeilds").attr('name', 'myid').show();
 $("#addNew").hide();
 $("#addNew1").show();
});
```

```css
.verticalLine {
    border-left: thick solid #0accff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form>
<label>Your Profile</label>
<div class="row" id="mainContainer">
 <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4">
  <label for="Education">Education</label>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-8 verticalLine" id="nestedFeilds" style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left; display:none;">
  <a href="" style="color: red;float:right; ">Delete Education</a>
  <input type="text" placeholder="School Name" class="form-control" id="School_Name" required="" name="School_Name">
  <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Feild of Study" class="form-control" id="feild_Name" required="" name="feild_Name">
  <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Degree" class="form-control" id="Degree_Name" required="" name="Degree_Name">
  <br>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="YearName" style="float:left;" required="" name="first_year_name" value=''>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
     </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control" style="margin-left: -20px; float:left;" id="monthName" required="" name="first_Name_month" value=''>Select Month
      <option value='01'>January</option>
     </select>
   </div>
   <div style="margin-left: -20px;float:left;">
    <p style="text-align: left; margin-top: 5px">&nbsp;to</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="YearName" style="margin-right:30px; float:left;" required="" name="second_year_name" value=''>Select Month
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
     </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="monthName" style="float:left; margin-left: -20px;" required="" name="Second__Name_month"
     value=''>Select Month
       <option value='01'>January</option>
     </select>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div style="float:left;"><a id="addNew"> Add Education</a></div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="2ndmainContainer" style="display:none;">
 <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4"></div>
 <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-8 verticalLine" id="showhere" style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left;">
 </div>
</div>

<div style="margin-left: 133px;float:left;"><a id="addNew1" style="display:none;"> Add Education</a></div>
</form>
```

Comment: sir firstly thank you for your  answer it is giving me  my type of answer but i just share the link why it is not talking full width so my select box can have its space sir kindly have a look

Comment: You can change `col-md-5` to `col-md-6` or `col-md-7`. This will increase the column width for second column. Updated code above.

Comment: thank you so much sir can you help me bit more i want add education to be inline with label my float left is not working and delete education to right corner of input feild here margin left is working but it is not responsive

Comment: thankyouu i just look today was thinking that you are  not helping any more but sir still add education link is not inline  with  education

Comment: You want `Add Education` link on top? Didn't get your question.

Comment: sir to making you clear my question reveiw this link

Comment: i am making sort of replica of this  here education and add education link is inline i want the same view

Comment: thank you so much for your effort but it is not working even click function is not working

Comment: Above snippet is working for me (tested in chrome). Which click function?

Comment: sir i am also testing in chrome  sir why are you using  myid and addnew and addnew1 click

Comment: sir can you please explain  your code so that i can rectify my  mistake that why mine is not working

Comment: sir even on fiddle it is not working please review this

Comment: Your code in fiddle works. You need to include references to jQuery, bootstrap. Copy the script and link tags in my code above and paste in JSFiddle above `Your Profile` label. I just verified and it works.

Comment: sir should i copy these links to my  local host project also because  the same code does not work for me :(

Comment: Yes. You need to have these files. Otherwise the code will not work. Either copy the links in above snippet as is to your project or download the files and then put it in your web server. For bootstrap, you will need to download the entire library.

Comment: sir thankyou so much for your advice but now my jquery is completely changes and  update by you code i am confuse how to do it please help me again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156761/discussion-between-ramii-and-phani-kumar-m).

Comment: sir please @ Phani Kumar M explain me this line